# Flask: each route in its own module file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, restful-architecture

I have am developing a flask app that is both a regular website (serving HTML) and and a JSON API.  It's structured like this (using blueprints for `api` and `site`)

```
Project
 |
 +-- views
 |  |  
 |  +-- api.py      <-- all routes for api
 |  +-- site.py     <-- all routes for regular site
 |
 +-- __init__.py
 +-- category.py    <-- main project dir contains shared object modules
 +-- helpers.py
 +-- product.py  
 ...
```

That works OK, except that as the project grows, having all the routes in the `api.py` and `site.py` modules causes them to grow a mile long.

I'd like to split out each route into its own module like this:

```
 Project
 |
 +-- views
 |  |  
 +  |-- api
 |  |  |
 |  |  +-- __init__.py 
 |  |  +-- cart.py        <-- each route has its own file
 |  |  +-- category.py
 |  |  +-- user.py 
 |  |  +-- ... 
 |  |  |
 +  |-- site 
 |  |  +-- __init__.py 
 |  |  +-- cart.py
 |  |  +-- category.py
 |  |  +-- user.py 
 |  |  +-- ... 
 |  |   
 +-- __init__.py
 +-- category.py 
 +-- helpers.py
 +-- product.py     
 ...
```

Or at least into modules that are grouped together like `/user` and all `/user/*` sub-routes would be put into `./views/api/user.py` (for example).

How can this be accomplished?  or, is there a better way to approach?

Comment: It's a question of personal taste, I'll go for first option with code shared between pages separated. Also remember that if your API should do same as regular site, you can write only the API and let the site call the API (you'll only need templates). Also sharing code gives the plus that in case of changes you'll have to put hands only in one place,

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research of blueprints, I realized that I was not really fully understanding and utilizing them.  One of their main purposes is to chunk-ify route modules that are a mile long.